BibTex generating .aux file with incorrect \bibdata
Sorry if this is a noob question, this is my first attempt using LaTeX for typesetting (and I'm loving it so far). I'm setting up a document for my dissertation using my university's template (Using MiKTeX with TeXworks). Each individual chapter is in it's own folder with it's own .bib.
Thesis.tex:
\usepackage{cite}

\usepackage[sectionbib]{chapterbib}

\usepackage{achemso}

Chapter-2.tex:
\bibliographystyle{achemso}

\bibliography{Chapter-2}

Chapter-2.aux:
\bibdata{acs-Thesis,Chapter-2}

I have to manually correct the file path (deleting out "acs-Thesis") in the aux file everytime I compile.
Does anyone have any insight into what I'm doing wrong with this? Appreciate the help in advance.

it would be much easier to help if you provided a small complete test document that showed the problem and allowed answers to be tested.

Welcome to TeX.SX! As David writes: Please construct a small document that illustrates the problem. Add the contents of the few files making up the document to your post and describe the steps that lead to the problem. At the moment, there is not enough information: The problem may result from code that you do not show, or from the way you process the files, etc

Why do you think this is incorrect? It's by-design with achemso.

So by design with achemso I am expected to manually update the file path? If I leave the original argument it will error out.

@cman22 What path? acs-... is stem added to the jobname when creating a file acs-<jobname>.bib

Please clarify your specific problem or provide additional details to highlight exactly what you need. As it's currently written, it's hard to tell exactly what you're asking.
